# Формирование документов WORD из списков python

Tags: python, list, ms-word, python-docx, docxtpl

У меня есть шаблон
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть 2 списка

```
['2021-04-30', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-06']

[1500, 450, 750, 900]
```

Код:

```
doc = DocxTemplate('Шаблон.docx')
context = {'expirationdate': date, 'price': price, 'finalprice': pricesum}
doc.render(context)
doc.save('restyled.docx')
```

Я получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне получить такой документ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую вот так

```
х=0
while х<len(date):
    doc = DocxTemplate('Шаблон.docx')
    context = {'expirationdate': date[х], 'price': price[х], 'finalprice': pricesum}
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save('restyled.docx')
```

Но тогда получаю только первый элемент списка и только одну строку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основе второй части ("Dynamic table") вот этого ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983642/4752653 (код там взят из [одного из тестов](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/dynamic_table.py) к python-docx-template)

Шаблон делаем такого вида:

[image: Шаблон]

Строки таблицы, обрамленные в `tr for`/`tr endfor`, будут дублироваться столько раз, сколько элементов в списке по ключу `'tbl_contents'`. Для дублирования колонок нужно использовать `tc for`/`tc endfor` вместо `tr for`/`tr endfor` (как в примере в [данном шаблоне](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/dynamic_table_tpl.docx)).

Код заполнения:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')

dates = ['2021-04-30', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-06']
prices = [1500, 450, 750, 900]

# Формируем список вида
# [{'expirationdate': '2021-04-30', 'price': 1500},
#  {'expirationdate': '2021-05-02', 'price': 450}, ...]
tbl_contents = [{'expirationdate': expirationdate, 'price': price}
                for expirationdate, price in zip(dates, prices)]

context = {
    'tbl_contents': tbl_contents,
    'finalprice': sum(prices)
}

doc.render(context)
doc.save('result.docx')
```

Результат:
[image: Результат]

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Все работает. А можно как-то открыть файл после сохранения?

Comment: Открыть в ворде? Что-то типа `import os` `os.system("имя_файла.docx")` - под Windows откроется в ассоциированном приложении, скорее всего в ворде.

Comment: Видимо os и моя директория проекта различаются. Пишет нет такого файла

Comment: Тогда пробуйте полный путь указывать. Вообще, по идее, если по относительному пути через `doc.save('result.docx')` записалось, то точно так же через `os.system('result.docx')` должно и открыться. Проверьте еще на всякий случай, что имена файлов совпадают.

Comment: `doc.save("Static.docx")
    os.system("Static.docx") ` Получаю ошибку sh: 1: Static.docx: not found

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: У меня WSL Debian(утилита linux для windows)

Comment: Через WSL не факт что получится. Вообще попробуйте `os.system("/usr/bin/xdg-open Static.docx")`

Comment: У меня веб-приложение и мне надо избегать таких путей

Comment: Если веб приложение, то os.system вообще не подойдет. Нужно просто отдавать файл на скачивание.