# Я хочу использовать библиотеку pywin32 для переноса расчетов в Word. Но для нее нет хорошей документации. Может есть какая-нибудь альтернатива pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, pywin32

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import win32com.client as win32
import pythoncom

wb_val = load_workbook(filename ='qw.xlsx',data_only=True)
sheet_val = wb_val['Лист1']
b2_val = sheet_val['A2'].value
fc = sheet_val['B']
number_of_lines = sheet_val.max_row-1 #количество строк
# print(q)
number = []
for row in range(2,sheet_val.max_row+1): #проход по столбцу
    number.append(sheet_val['B'+str(row)].value)
average_speed = sum(number)/number_of_lines #вычесление средней
average_speed = round(average_speed,2)
print(average_speed)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Я хочу использовать библиотеку pywin32 для переноса расчетов в Word. Но для нее нет хорошей документации. Может есть какая-нибудь альтернатива pywin32.

Comment: Нужно расчеты перенести или результаты расчетов? Можно docxtpl использовать для создания документов word (в том числе табличных) по шаблону. См. например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280467/1365

Comment: Перенести результат расчетов. уже в готовый ячейки документа Word